# What is the proper business address format when office is in located in another unrelated business?

Tags: united-states, offices, business-cards

I rent office space inside another company. Is there a proper/formal format for writing out my address on business correspondence?

Just an example...

[image]

Would that be the way to do it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'm a little surprised there isn't a suite # associated w the address, especially in the US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's this easy ..

```
Good Guys Gaming
1st Floor, 900 Silver Lane
Engle Cove, CO 12345
United States
```

Dan's answer forgot the 1st floor, which I recommend and which is perfectly professional.

(Note, in different countries that format is different, example "900 Silver Lane, 1st Floor" .. "1/900 Silver Lane" .. whatever is correct locally.)

You simply **don't need to mention** "Marley Purveyors". It will find you.

Note however that this sort of thing is perfectly common and acceptable these days:

```
Good Guys Gaming
Marley Office Center
900 Silver Lane
Engle Cove, CO 12345
United States
```

Things like "distributed offices" and "coloc offices" and so on are common today.  And it's fine to state them.

```
Good Guys Gaming
Supertrendy Coloc Design Offices
900 Silver Lane
Engle Cove, CO 12345
United States
```

That sounds great, no problem there.

Comment: This is fine for receiving mail, but an address for visitors would likely need further details about being inside Mary Jane Purveyors.

Comment: Generally I don't think so, Eric - once someone is there on the spot, (A) there will be small signs for the sub-tenants or (B) they would have to ask anyway - and no matter what it said on the instructions, they'd have to ask, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to confuse your customers any more than necessary.

What you propose works, but it makes you look very small.

For the cost of postage, you can send a test letter to

> Good Guys Gaming
>   900 Silver Lane
>   Engle Cove, CO 12345
>   United States

and see if it arrives.

If that doesn't work, consider renting a mailbox.